# How to see selected options combined with another ones in console log?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I need to see two values together in console like 
2 times Kişi ekleme,
3 times Proje Açma, etc.

There are multiple rows in page with same classes.
So i need to combine two values which are in same row.

But need to get each of them.
Quantities comes from numeric input boxes and second one comes from dropdown select.

How can i combine them in console.log(); ?
By the way i am adding the selectbox via append.
And there are no value attrs for select options.

This code shows `.ex`'s and `.span2`'s but not together.

```
$('.ex').find(':selected').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).text())
})

$(".span2").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});

return;
```

I am trying to print them as an array and trying to control if there is a selected option which is selected more than once on other dropdowns.

Here is the html. Adding rows to repeatable part by clicking.

```
   <div class="row" style="background-color: #ecf0f5; padding: 15px 35px;">

     <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class="repeatable"></div>

        <form class="form-horizontal" style="margin-left: 0x!important;">


            <fieldset class="todos_labels">

                <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
                    <br><input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-success add" align="center"><br>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
  <input type="button" id="btnSavePackagetab2" class="form-control btn btn-success" style="width: 14%;float: right;"value="Kaydet">
        </form>

    </div>


</div>
</div>
```

And this is the append part.

```
$(".repeatable").append('<div class="field-group row"><br><div class="col-lg-6"><label for="" style="text-align:left">Package</label><select class="form-control ex" id="selectiontab2"><option>Seçiniz</option><option>Cv Görüntüleme</option><option>Proje Açma</option><option>Kişi Ekleme</option><option>CV İletişim Bilgileri Görüntüleme</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-4"><label for="">Quantity</label><input type="number" class="span2 form-control" min="0" id=""></div><div class="col-lg-2"><label for=""></label><br><br></div></div>');
```

Comment: Share your html code as well

Comment: Combine them. Each select has a corresponding value box. So when you loop over the selects concat a string containing the selected text value and the value of the input box adjacent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the parent element that contains both types of elements (i.e. `.row`), and then use the same selectors you had (but within the `this` scope) inside the `each` callback:

```
$('.row').each(function () {
    console.log( $('.ex > :selected', this).text(), $('.span2', this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

You loop over each select with your jQuery function. While a select is found, we can traverse up the DOM and select the input adjacent to it.

```js
function add() {
  $(".repeatable").append('<div class="field-group row"><br><div class="col-lg-6"><label for="" style="text-align:left">Package</label><select class="form-control ex" id="selectiontab2"><option>Seçiniz</option><option>Cv Görüntüleme</option><option>Proje Açma</option><option>Kişi Ekleme</option><option>CV İletişim Bilgileri Görüntüleme</option></select></div><div class="col-lg-4"><label for="">Quantity</label><input type="number" class="span2 form-control" min="0" id=""></div><div class="col-lg-2"><label for=""></label><br><br></div></div>');
};
add();
add();

$('.ex').find(':selected').each(function () {
   let stringValueConsole = $(this).text();
   stringValueConsole += ": " +$(this).parent("div.row").find("input.span2").val();
   console.log(stringValueConsole);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="background-color: #ecf0f5; padding: 15px 35px;">

  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="repeatable"></div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" style="margin-left: 0x!important;">


      <fieldset class="todos_labels">

        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left;">
          <br><input type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-success add" align="center"><br>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
      <input type="button" id="btnSavePackagetab2" class="form-control btn btn-success" style="width: 14%;float: right;" value="Kaydet">
    </form>

  </div>


</div>
</div>
```